# VB.NET 2012 Report Viewer Error

Tags: vb.net, report, reportviewer

I get following error on subreport "**data retrieval failed for the subreport please check the log files**". When I run separate reports it works fine but when I include as subreport it gives the above error. Pleas help me thanks.

Comment: did you do as it suggests? "check the log files"

Comment: What are you speaking about? I suppose this information is too few even to understand what you mean.

Comment: Imagine we have no idea what you're talking about, what your reports look like or what underlying logic you're using. If you imagine all that - how would you ask your question?

Comment: I am passing a parameter from main report to subreport, When I test two reports separately work fine no errors. But when I include the subreport in main report it gives that error on Subreport content, main report works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The actual text is down to when you don't call this in the SubreportProcessing event handler of the ReportViewer.LocalReport object.

```
Dim tbl As DataTable = GetDataForYourSubReport()
Dim rptDataSource As New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", tbl)
e.DataSources.Add(rptDataSource)
```

The error message from the report viewer component is particularly unhelpful though, there are no log files, it's talking about log files from the application that may or may not exist!!

I had the same error mesage where on some machines you got the error you describe but on some you don't.
It was due to the fact that the e.ReportPath was null where it should have contained the report name.

This lack of ReportPath Was a bug in an older version of the Report Viewer DLL that was installed in the GAC on the machines where it breaks (The one that ships with SQL Server 2012 has a bug where the e.ReportPath parameter is passed in as null)

If you do have code in the SubreportProcessing event handler get the "machine specific" behaviour then try downloading and installing the latest "Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 runtime" on the machines where it breaks.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35747